# merge datasets with conditions in r

Tags: r

I have a data set which looks like the following:

[image: df1]

The 'X19' is the row number of another data set. How can I merge these two data sets such that 'FNUMM' will be added to each row appears in 'X19'?

[image: df2]

Thanks.

Comment: Please don't post an image of the data, but rather a sample of your data.frame(s) (e.g. post the output of `dput(head(DF,10))`). See [how to make a great reproducible example](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5963269/how-to-make-a-great-r-reproducible-example)

Comment: ..and possibly post both data.frame's. In your image I see just one, and honestly I don't understand what are you trying to accomplish...

Comment: Sry I don't really know how to post a sample... I'll just post another image of the dataframe.

Comment: Paste into your question the output of `dput(head(df1,10))` and `dput(head(df2,10))`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is a merge where one of the keys is the `rownames` of one dataset. You can do this:

```
 cbind(df1, df2[, "FNUMM"][match(rownames(df1), df2$X19)])
```

Here is a reproducible example

```
df1 <- data.frame(ID=c(1L,1L,1L,1L,2L,2L,3L,3L), 
                 var=c(1:8), Smoke=c('No','No','Yes','No','No','No','Yes','No'))

df2 <- data.frame(X19=c(2,5,8), FNUMM=c('a','b','c'))

cbind(df1, df2[, "FNUMM"][match(rownames(df1), df2$X19)])
```

Answer (score 1):

Try `merge(df1, df2, by = 'X19')`, where df1 and df2 are your two data frames.

Comment: It says "Error in fix.by(by.x, x) : 'by' must specify a uniquely valid column". I guess that is because df1 and df2 do not have the same number of rows.

Comment: Or can you tell me if I can manipulate the df w/ less rows so that it has as many rows as the other df?

Comment: Kind of difficult to tell, since I can't reproduce your data or at least part of it to see what's going on.